# How to split pandas series into key value?

Tags: python, dataframe, key

I want to split pandas series into the key and value pair. My program is converting it into the key and value pairs but I want this key and value in well format.

Input text file contains following data :

**Input.txt-**

```
3=123|4=88|5=M|8=75|9=29
3=38|4=13|5=I|8=17.3|9=10|1021=0|854=p|394=7.73|474=7.7477558
```

**Program-Code-**

```
    df = pd.read_csv(inputfile, index_col=None, names=['text'])
    df_list = df.values.T.tolist()
    s = df.text.str.split('|')
    splited_list = s.values.T.tolist()
    s1 = pd.Series(splited_list)
    ds = [dict(w.split('=', 1) for w in x) for x in s1]
    p = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ds)
    p1 = p.replace(np.nan,'n/a', regex=True)
    st = p1.stack(level=0,dropna=False)
    dfs = [g for i, g in st.groupby(level=0)]
    dfs_length = len(dfs)
    i = 0
    while i < dfs_length:
       #index of each column
       print '\nindex[%d]'%i
       for k,v in dfs[i].iteritems():
          print k,' : ',v
       i = i + 1
```

This produces following output :

**output-**

```
index[0]
(0, '1021')  :  n/a
(0, '3')  :  123
(0, '394')  :  n/a
(0, '4')  :  88
(0, '474')  :  n/a
(0, '5')  :  M
(0, '8')  :  75
(0, '854')  :  n/a
(0, '9')  :  29

index[1]
(1, '1021')  :  0
(1, '3')  :  38
(1, '394')  :  7.73
(1, '4')  :  13
(1, '474')  :  7.7477558
(1, '5')  :  I
(1, '8')  :  17.3
(1, '854')  :  p
(1, '9')  :  10
```

I want output in the other format. I want this n/a contents in the end of each result if present and I want to remove index and brackets of the keys. Also output contents should be in the same order that are available in the input file.

Expected Output :

```
index[0]
3       123
4       88
5       M
8       75
9       29
1021    n/a
394     n/a
474     n/a
854     n/a

index[1]
3       38
4       13
5       I
8       17.3
9       10
1021    0
854     p    
394     7.73
474     7.7477558
```

Any suggestions about how can I get this type of output?

Comment: Please include sample data in your post so that your example is reproducible.

Comment: @BrenBarn- yes sure see Input.txt.

Comment: @BrenBarn- Any difficulty to understand this question?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer half of your question. To get rid of the brackets and the index, you need to slightly adjust your code such as:

```
i = 0
while i < len(dfs):    
    #index of each column
    print ('\nindex[%d]'%i)
    for (_,k),v in dfs[i].iteritems():
        print (k,' : ',v)
    i = i + 1
```

The result then looks like this:

```
index[0]
1021  :  n/a
3  :  123
394  :  n/a
4  :  88
474  :  n/a
5  :  M
8  :  75
854  :  n/a
9  :  29

index[1]
1021  :  0
3  :  38
394  :  7.73
4  :  13
474  :  7.7477558
5  :  I
8  :  17.3
854  :  p
9  :  10
```

Finally, regarding the order of the output, the solution will change something about this line:

```
ds = [dict(w.split('=', 1) for w in x) for x in s1]
```

Because s1 still contains the right order, whereas ds does not:

s1

```
0                       [3=123, 4=88, 5=M, 8=75, 9=29]
1    [3=38, 4=13, 5=I, 8=17.3, 9=10, 1021=0, 854=p,...
dtype: object
```

ds

```
[{'3': '123', '4': '88', '5': 'M', '8': '75', '9': '29'},
 {'1021': '0',
  '3': '38',
  '394': '7.73',
  '4': '13',
  '474': '7.7477558',
  '5': 'I',
  '8': '17.3',
  '854': 'p',
  '9': '10'}]
```

It seems to me that the keys for the dict are automatically sorted as strings which explains why 1021 comes before 3. I though about sorting them by ascending, but this would not yield the order as your requested from the txt data. Thus I do not know the solution and I am also curious for the answer.